# how to display grouped products in single product page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using wordpress 3.9.2 and woocommerce 2.1.1.

I want to dispay all the grouped products in the single product detail page.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce does this by default for Grouped Products: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/chained-products-vs-product-bundles-vs-force-sells-vs-grouped-products/#section-5.  If you setup your products correctly, you shouldn't have to do anything special.  The should appear together on the single product page.